# Where can i change the color of objects in LIBGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am just getting to know LIBGDX library and need to change the color of all objects to different shades of purple. I thought that by putting all objects of the same type e.g Pegs, Walls, catchers each into arraylists and then iterating trough them and setting the color in the `render()` int the `Play` class but nothing changes.

This was my initial idea:

```
sb.setColor(Color.PINK);
for (RoundPeg peg : pegs) {
    peg.draw(sb);
}
```

My relevant code:

public Play(GameStateManager gsm) {
super(gsm);

```
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, gravity), true);
    world.setContactListener(new GameContactListener());
    b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    int x= (int) (PPM/2); //feste x Pos evtl.
    placePegs();
    placeWalls();
    placeCatchers();
   // dropBall(MathUtils.random(100, 300));
    dropBall(250);//siehe x


    // Set up camera
    b2dcam = new OrthographicCamera();
    b2dcam.setToOrtho(false, Game.WIDTH / PPM, Game.HEIGHT / PPM);

}


private void placePegs() {
    int numRows = 9;
    pegs = new ArrayList<RoundPeg>();
    for (int row = numRows; row >= 1; row--) {
        for (int col = 1; col <= row; col++) {
            int x = (int) (Game.WIDTH * (col + (numRows - row) / 2.0) * 10 / PPM); // x-Position
            int y = (int) (Game.HEIGHT * (numRows - row + 1) * 8 / PPM); // y-Position
            RoundPeg peg = new RoundPeg(x, y, world, Color.PURPLE);
            pegs.add(peg);
        }
    }
    // 9 Peg rows
     /*for (int i = 10; i < 100; i = i + 10) {
        for (int j = 10; j < 100; j = j + 10) {
            RoundPeg peg = new RoundPeg((int) (Game.WIDTH * i / PPM), (int) ((Game.HEIGHT * j) / PPM), world);

        }
    }


    // 3 Peg rows
    for (int i = 25; i < 100; i = i + 25) {
        for (int j = 120; j < 700; j = j + 160) {
            RoundPeg peg = new RoundPeg((int) (Game.WIDTH * i / PPM), (int) j, world);
        }
    }

    // 2 Peg Rows wide
    for (int i = 15; i < 100; i = i + 70) {
        for (int j = 200; j < 700; j = j + 160) {
            RoundPeg peg = new RoundPeg((int) (Game.WIDTH * i / PPM), (int) j, world);
        }
    }

    // 2 Peg rows narrow
    for (int i = 35; i < 90; i = i + 30) {
        RoundPeg peg = new RoundPeg((int) (Game.WIDTH * i / PPM), 355, world);
    } */


}

private void placeWalls() {
    BodyDef bdef;
    FixtureDef fdef;
    PolygonShape shape;

    bdef = new BodyDef();
    fdef = new FixtureDef();
    shape = new PolygonShape();

    // Left Wall
    bdef.position.set(0 / PPM, 0 / PPM);
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    Body body = world.createBody(bdef);
    shape.setAsBox(5 / PPM, Game.HEIGHT / PPM);
    fdef.shape = shape;
    fdef.filter.categoryBits = Box2dVars.BIT_WALLS;
    fdef.filter.maskBits = Box2dVars.BIT_BALL;

    body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("wall");


    // Right wall
    bdef.position.set(Game.WIDTH / PPM, 0 / PPM);
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    Body body1 = world.createBody(bdef);
    shape.setAsBox(5 / PPM, Game.HEIGHT / PPM);
    fdef.shape = shape;
    fdef.filter.categoryBits = Box2dVars.BIT_WALLS;
    fdef.filter.maskBits = Box2dVars.BIT_BALL;
    body1.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("wall");

    // Bottom wall
    bdef.position.set(0 / PPM, 0 / PPM);
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    Body body2 = world.createBody(bdef);
    shape.setAsBox(Game.WIDTH / PPM, 5 / PPM);
    fdef.shape = shape;
    fdef.filter.categoryBits = Box2dVars.BIT_WALLS;
    fdef.filter.maskBits = Box2dVars.BIT_BALL;
    body2.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("wall");
}

private void placeCatchers() {
    BodyDef bdef;
    FixtureDef fdef;
    PolygonShape shape;

    bdef = new BodyDef();
    fdef = new FixtureDef();
    shape = new PolygonShape();

    for (int i = 10; i < 100; i = i + 10) {
        bdef.position.set((Game.WIDTH * i / PPM) / PPM, 0);
        bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
        Body body = world.createBody(bdef);
        shape.setAsBox(5 / PPM, 30 / PPM);
        fdef.shape = shape;
        fdef.filter.categoryBits = Box2dVars.BIT_WALLS;
        fdef.filter.maskBits = Box2dVars.BIT_BALL;
        body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("wall");
        System.out.println("placing catcher");
    }
}

@Override
public void handleInput() {


}
//Bitmap
private void dropBall(int posX){

    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();

    bdef.position.set(posX / PPM, 790 / PPM);
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

    // Randomly drop ball
    Body body = world.createBody(bdef);
    CircleShape cshape = new CircleShape();
    cshape.setRadius(13 / PPM);
    fdef.shape = cshape;
    fdef.filter.categoryBits = Box2dVars.BIT_BALL;
    fdef.filter.maskBits = Box2dVars.BIT_WALLS | Box2dVars.BIT_PEG;
    fdef.restitution = 0.7f;
    fdef.density = 0.9f;
    fdef.friction = 0.1f;
    body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("ball");
}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    world.step(dt, 6, 2);


}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    b2dr.render(world, b2dcam.combined);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    world.dispose();
    b2dr.dispose();

}


public class Game implements ApplicationListener {

public static final String TITLE = "Plinko";
public static final int WIDTH = 480;
public static final int HEIGHT = 800;

public static final float STEP = 1 / 60f;
private float accum;

private SpriteBatch sb;
private OrthographicCamera cam;
private OrthographicCamera hudCam;

private GameStateManager gsm;

@Override
public void create() {
    sb = new SpriteBatch();
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    hudCam = new OrthographicCamera();
    hudCam.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    gsm = new GameStateManager(this);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    accum += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    while (accum >- STEP) {
        accum -= STEP;
        gsm.update(STEP);
        gsm.render();
    }
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}


@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    sb.dispose();
}

// Getters And Setters
public SpriteBatch getSpriteBatch() {
    return sb;
}
public OrthographicCamera getCamera() {
    return cam;
}

public OrthographicCamera getHUDCamera() {
    return hudCam;
}
```

and the `RoundPeg` class:

```
public class RoundPeg {

private final  com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color color;
private BodyDef bdef;
private FixtureDef fdef;
private PolygonShape shape;
private CircleShape cshape;

public RoundPeg(int posX, int posY, World world, com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color color) {

   bdef = new BodyDef();

    bdef.position.set(posX / PPM, posY / PPM);
    fdef = new FixtureDef();
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
    Body body = world.createBody(bdef);

    cshape = new CircleShape();
    cshape.setRadius(4 / PPM);
    fdef.shape = cshape;

    fdef.filter.categoryBits = Box2dVars.BIT_PEG;
    fdef.filter.maskBits = Box2dVars.BIT_BALL;
    body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("peg");
    this.color= color;

}
```

}

Game class:

```
public class Game implements ApplicationListener {

public static final String TITLE = "Plinko";
public static final int WIDTH = 480;
public static final int HEIGHT = 800;

public static final float STEP = 1 / 60f;
private float accum;

private SpriteBatch sb;
private OrthographicCamera cam;
private OrthographicCamera hudCam;

private GameStateManager gsm;

@Override
public void create() {
    sb = new SpriteBatch();
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    hudCam = new OrthographicCamera();
    hudCam.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    gsm = new GameStateManager(this);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    accum += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    while (accum >- STEP) {
        accum -= STEP;
        gsm.update(STEP);
        gsm.render();
    }
}


@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}


@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    sb.dispose();
}

// Getters And Setters
public SpriteBatch getSpriteBatch() {
    return sb;
}
public OrthographicCamera getCamera() {
    return cam;
}

public OrthographicCamera getHUDCamera() {
    return hudCam;
}
```

}

Comment: What does your peg.draw() method look like?

Comment: I actually do not have draw() method, i just thought i could use it from LIBGDX, like others did in some tutorials

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the color on the individual sprites not the spritebatch.

Comment: Where would i do that and what would be the individual sprite in my case?

Comment: in the ```b2dr``` which is your renderer i assumed you were adding sprites because ```sb``` sounds like short for ```spriteBatch```. so when you just as you add the sprite change the color there.

Comment: The OP does not appear to be using the Sprite class, so setting the color on the batch would be correct. IMO, it's best not to use the Sprite class, since it conflates an asset (the texture/texture region) with a game world object that includes properties about world position and orientation and per-unit color. Poor modularity/encapsulation, and a violation of the single responsibility principle.

Comment: So my idea is right? I do not understand why it still won't work. No errors, the colors just remain the same as before (black with green lines)

Comment: You said you don't have a draw() method, so I don't know what your actual code is to be able to tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: updated my post. Added the Game class.